# How can I Record video from webcam on client with lossless frame pixels through browser?

Tags: node.js, angular, opencv, video-processing

I need to build a website which recording the person from the camera (he must allow the camera first), but I need the record frame by frame with lossless pixels.
I tried to figure this out with some options:

1. opencv.js - didn't figure it, it is using the browser video element, this is changing the pixels by compressions right?
2. ngx-webcame - I read it using capturing lossless images but not video

Now the other issue that I need to send the frames to the server?
should I save the frames on client process it on client computer and then send the result to the server?
Is there an option to send the video data frame to the server for future use?

Someone told me to build an agent that will do this actions and send the data on chunks but in that case I don't know really how to do it and I need clarification on that and some instruction on how to start build something like that.

If anyone have an example codes or anything that can direct me to the solution it will be very helpful.

Comment: Sending the live color video stream uncompressed needs a stupid high bandwidth of Width x Height x 3 x fps Bytes per Second.  Even for 640x480 this is 180 Mbit/s, so you probably want to record on client side and send over longer time later, if not working reliably on a very fast connection.

Comment: OK, I want to record on client side without any manipulation of the browser and do some processes on the video frames and then send the final data to my server, how can I do that or Can you point me to the right direction how to do it? if there any example codes it will be best!

Comment: sorry, I dont have experience with webbrowser applications. Probably you will need some javascript opencv stuff and write the raw images as files (.png or .bmp) to a .zip archive or sth.. To prevent manipulation you could compute a hash sum (like SHA or CRC) of each image file or maybe use an encrypted .zip file. I dont know, whether the user would be able to manipulate the images before computation of the hash files or before encrypting, e.g. whether he could just manipulate your script.

Answer (score 0):

I've created something similar befor using RecordRTC.

It takes advantageg of WebRTC. It works pretty straitforward. Record the video localy and upload it as a file.

https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC

Comment: Is it record the video direct from the camera without compression or pixels manipulation of the browser?

Comment: It has been a while since I've used it so can't say for sure. You'll have to dig into the documentation I guess.

Comment: This is what I can't find in any documentations, I need help with that...

Comment: What is the reason for wanting anything uncompressed? You'd want it in a specific video format anyway. That means selecting a container and a codec.

If you'd just want pixel data you might be able to do it using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia and writing the data to a canvas. the canvas could then in turn read out every pixel on the canvas. That should  be lossless. But it would also be really heavy

Comment: I need it uncompressed because I need the raw data as is without changing the pixels colors or brightness or anything in the pixels colors. I have been told that the browser and VideoElement and MediaStream Recorder do that compress on the raw data Is that true or I have got a wrong information?

Comment: Couldn't say for sure, but if it is then it would also be browser specific and thus Chrome could use differrent compressions as firefox. I don't think I can help you any further, this is all the information I have at hand.